# Save URL in Codeigniter Session Data

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, get

I am using codigniter to redirect users after they have logged in to the page they were on before.

an example url may be:

http://alpha.scrollr.co/app?tile=TITLE&credit=CREDIT&caption=CAPTION

Here is the code to save the url

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

 $this->session->set_userdata('redirect', $actual_link);
```

and this is used to retrieve it once they have logged in:

```
$actual_link = $this->session->userdata('redirect');
```

However I can not retrieve the actual_link I have more that one GET parameter in the url.

Any ideas

Comment: you mean you want to redirect back user to previous page after they login or something else

Comment: Updated it sorry: I mean I can not access $actual_link

Answer (score 2):

Maybe i too late, but maybe someone need it. You can do it by urlencode and decode. For example:

```
$url = 'https://example.com/';
      $this->session->set_userdata('url',urlencode($url));
```

And when you want to take the url.you can make like this:

```
$myurl = urldecode($_SESSION['url']);
      echo $myurl;
```

For unset, just simple like this:

```
unset($_SESSION['url']);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the get variables to a session.

Like this:

```
$domain = current_url(); //http://alpha.scrollr.co/app
$this->session->set_userdata('tile'   , 'TITLE'); //stores the title
$this->session->set_userdata('credit' , 'CREDIT'); //stores the credit
$this->session->set_userdata('caption', 'CAPTION'); //stores the caption
```

Then you can **UNSET** them after.

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('tile');
$this->session->unset_userdata('credit');
$this->session->unset_userdata('caption');
```

Comment: Does get current_url keep my get parameters

Comment: As what I've learned from the URL Helper. current_url() - fetches the whole URL. You should at least consult URL HELPER of CodeIgniter, it is quiet handy (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the get variables to the session?

Like this:

```
$domain = current_url(); //http://alpha.scrollr.co/app
$this->session->set_userdata('tile'   , 'TITLE'); //stores the title
$this->session->set_userdata('credit' , 'CREDIT'); //stores the credit
$this->session->set_userdata('caption', 'CAPTION'); //stores the caption
```

Then you can **UNSET** them after.

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('tile');
$this->session->unset_userdata('credit');
$this->session->unset_userdata('caption');
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to be very smart. Codeigniter is already very smart;

Just do like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * set session variable 'redirect'
 * with URL and query string
 */
$this->session->set_userdata ( 'redirect', current_url () . '?'. $this->input->server ( 'QUERY_STRING' ) );

/**
 * get session variable 'redirect'
 * with URL and query <string></string>
 * and redirect to user
 */
redirect ( $this->session->userdata ( 'redirect' ) );

/*
If URL is: 
http://localhost/development/ci-admin-with-template/index.php?test=pass&user=valid
User will Redirect on: 
http://localhost/development/ci-admin-with-template/index.php?test=pass&user=valid

If URL is: 
http://localhost/development/ci-admin-with-template/?test=pass&user=valid
User will Redirect on: 
http://localhost/development/ci-admin-with-template/index.php?test=pass&user=valid
*/
?>
```